# how replicate in mysql Crypto JS formula?

Tags: javascript, mysql, cryptojs

I have the duty of decrypt some data in our database that was encrypted using Crypto js a year ago, I would like to know how I can replicate the formula in pure mysql scripting.

Our actual js formula is:

```
// Use Cipher Mode
var crypto = CryptoJS.lib.BlockCipherMode.extend();
crypto.Encryptor = crypto.extend({processBlock:function(a,b){this._cipher.encryptBlock(a,b)}});
crypto.Decryptor = crypto.extend({processBlock:function(a,b){this._cipher.decryptBlock(a,b)}});

// Passphrase + iv
var passphrase = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("46536b6e32674441484c7a5374554975");
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("2a4b04f4fa87f913b98c30bce9d7fe69");
var value = 'st5AC+HL09fKYRJ7TxdMhQ==';

var decryptedValue = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, passphrase, { iv: iv, mode: crypto, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

## UPDATE

I really want to understand the formula more than translate it, because what I understand is that I have to do next in mysql

```
SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-ecb';
select AES_DECRYPT('st5AC+HL09fKYRJ7TxdMhQ==',hex('46536b6e32674441484c7a5374554975'),hex('2a4b04f4fa87f913b98c30bce9d7fe69'))
```

The expected word is "Christos", but I just get null result.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. This looks like ECB mode, so this should get you going on your own.

Comment: how I can know if is ECB 128 or ECB256?

Comment: There is no such thing as ECB 128 or ECB 256. You mean AES-128 or AES-256. Since your key consists of 32 hex-encoded characters, those are 16 bytes which are 128 bit. This means that you're using AES-128

Comment: yeah thats is what I mean, because in mysql documentation mentions AES-128-ECB or AES-256-ECB, but is confusing for me I don't have to much experience on this.